# Box Integration my website babel3d.com

Tags: box-api

As I am new to BOX.NET. I don’t have any idea about box app.
How it is used and purpose of it.

I have a simple requirement I have some clients who are using my web service.
I want to integrate my website with box.net as my client are using box.net.

I want to download the files form the client account and parse these files at my end 
and upload it in their account without any user interference.

For development purpose how to proceed to achieve this task.

What i have done till now now
1. created a developer account in BOX.net
2. created a test app as shown in video(http://developers.blog.box.com/2013/05/17/get-box-access-tokens-in-2-quick-steps/)
3.I am able to create a file in box.net

Where i am stuck

1. refresh token is working only once how to create refresh token again programatically as i need to check my client folder weather file any new file is added in the folder so that i can download and parse at my end and upload the file in to his folder.

Please Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refresh tokens are single use.  When you call the [/token](http://developers.box.com/docs/#oauth-2-token) endpoint during the refresh operation, you will receive a new access and refresh token pair.  You will need to use this new refresh token for subsequent refresh operations.